# App crash when trying to load a large amount off data into my app

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, afnetworking, realm

I am trying to load a `JSON` of 40 000+ records into my `Realm Database`. Here is my function

```
AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [[AFJSONRequestOperation alloc]init];
[AFJSONRequestOperation addAcceptableContentTypes:[NSSet setWithObject:@"text/html"]];

operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON) {

    NSArray *relations = [JSON copy];
    NSLog(@"COUNT SI %d",relations.count);

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        NSArray *relations = [JSON copy];
        RLMRealm *realm = [RLMRealm defaultRealm];
        [realm beginWriteTransaction];

        for (NSDictionary *dict in relations) {
            Relation *relation = [[Relation alloc]init];

            relation.rel_address = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[dict valueForKey:@"Address"]];
            relation.rel_balanceTotal = [[dict valueForKey:@"BalanceTotal"]doubleValue];
            relation.rel_bank_country_code = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[dict valueForKey:@"BankCountryCode"]];
            relation.rel_bank_number = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[dict valueForKey:@"BankNumber"]];
            relation.rel_city = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[dict valueForKey:@"City"]];
            relation.rel_city_id = [[dict valueForKey:@"CityId"]intValue];
            relation.rel_code = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[dict valueForKey:@"Code"]];
            relation.rel_country = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[dict valueForKey:@"Country"]];
            relation.rel_country_code = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[dict valueForKey:@"CountryCode"]];
            relation.rel_customerProspect = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[dict valueForKey:@"CustomerProspect"]];
            relation.rel_customerCode = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[dict valueForKey:@"CustomerProspectCode"]];
            relation.rel_email = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[dict valueForKey:@"Email"]];
            relation.rel_expired_total = [[dict valueForKey:@"ExpiredTotal"]doubleValue];
            relation.rel_fax = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[dict valueForKey:@"Fax"]];
            relation.rel_gsm = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[dict valueForKey:@"GSM"]];
            relation.rel_latitude = [[dict valueForKey:@"Latitude"]doubleValue];
            relation.rel_longitude = [[dict valueForKey:@"Longitude"]doubleValue];
            relation.rel_memo = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[dict valueForKey:@"Memo"]];
            relation.rel_name = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[dict valueForKey:@"Name"]];
            relation.rel_phone = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[dict valueForKey:@"Phone"]];
            relation.rel_turnovertotal = [[dict valueForKey:@"TurnoverTotal"]doubleValue];
            relation.rel_vat_country_code = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[dict valueForKey:@"VATCountryCode"]];
            relation.rel_vat_number = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[dict valueForKey:@"VATNumber"]];
            relation.rel_website = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[dict valueForKey:@"Website"]];
            relation.rel_zipcode = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[dict valueForKey:@"ZipCode"]];
            [realm addObject:relation];
        }
        [realm commitWriteTransaction];
        compblock(YES);

    });


} failure:^( NSURLRequest *request ,NSHTTPURLResponse *response ,NSError *error , id JSON ){
    NSLog(@"error is %@",error);
}];
[operation start];
```

Everything works oké for 10 000 objects. But when I go to 40 000, I get this error:

```
Communications error: <OS_xpc_error: <error: 0x356dc614> { count = 1, contents =
    "XPCErrorDescription" => <string: 0x356dc86c> { length = 22, contents = "Connection interrupted" }
}>
```

Can anyone please help me? Thanks in advance !!

**EDIT**

It crashes before the "COUNT SI" log. So I think it has something to do with AFNetworking?
Also I noticed that it does not crashed on simulator...

Comment: Woooooow - dont' do it. Add pagination, use CoreData. Don't load this amount of data all at once - is really wroooong

Comment: Where is the data coming from?  Very likely, when you request that much data the server spends so much time building the response that the connection times out.  In a similar situation I've had to build in a heuristic to "tune" the size of requests if a connection times out.

Comment: Grzegorz Krukowski is right that you shouldn't load this much data into memory at once, but I see no reason to use Core Data over Realm for this. In fact, Realm will use less memory once the data has been inserted. The JSON parsing is what's taking an extraordinarily large amount of memory.

Comment: Hi Stef! Have you come up with any solution? I am having the same issue but with less number of records.

Comment: @Goti At the moment I've dropped the use of Core data and I'm using Realm now (www.realm.io) much faster !!!

Comment: @StefGeelen I have also got the solution by having NSMutableString instead of NSString. Just by appending string in NSMutableString object clears my way. Thanks btw.

Answer (score 7):

This problem is unrelated to Realm.

> I am trying to load a JSON of 40 000+ records

There's your problem. `AFJSONRequestOperation` will attempt to deserialize the JSON in memory and your app will no longer have any available memory, and will get terminated.

> Also I noticed that it does not crashed on simulator...

This is because the simulator has access to much more memory than an iOS device.

You should find ways to reduce the size of your network requests, either by requesting less data at a time or using a less wasteful response format than JSON strings.

Comment: Oke I'm now going to work with paging in my JSONs ! Thanks for the help !

Answer (score 2):

Wrap loop's body in `@autoreleasepool`

Also copying the same JSON twice seems redundant.