# XPCErrorDescription" => <string: 0x3623a854> { length = 22, contents = "Connection interrupted"

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios9, xcode7

What are the possible causes of this bug? This bug makes my application to crash with memory warning. I tried to browse the bug but got little help. Please help me...

The full Bug is:

```
Communications error: <OS_xpc_error: <error: 0x3623a654> { count = 1, contents =
"XPCErrorDescription" => <string: 0x3623a854> { length = 22, contents = "Connection interrupted" }
}>
2015-10-20 15:42:57.182 Wachiz[3187:205489] Received memory warning.
```

Comment: May be this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28795166/what-is-communications-error-os-xpc-error-in-xcode-6 can help.

Comment: So does it means that this is an apple daemon issue which cant be controlled by us? @DeepeshGairola

Comment: Although i never came across such issue but by searching about it on web it seems like data payload also matters for e.g. take a look here  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27276718/app-crash-when-trying-to-load-a-large-amount-off-data-into-my-app