# XPC communications error: XPC shuts down app during import of 4k+ contacts from address book. How to fix this and retain the functionality?

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-leaks, ipod, xpc

I was assigned to an app which I don't yet fully have domain knowledge of. In that app, I am importing contacts from Contact book to my app. It works fine on other devices but iPod is causing me trouble with a certain number of contacts. If contacts are <3k, everything works fine. If contacts are 4k+, the memory usage stats go off the chart:

[image]

This is insane. Now If I am lucky, sometimes it will just give me a low memory warning and keep working. Otherwise it just sends the app to background and in console I see this exception:

```
Communications error: <OS_xpc_error: <error: 0x3623a654> { count = 1, contents =
"XPCErrorDescription" => <string: 0x3623a854> { length = 22, contents = "Connection interrupted" }
}>
```

When I try to bring the app to foreground, I find that it is back on the login page (Start page) than on the page I left. So I am not sure if it is crashing or what. I guess it relaunches the app after clearing all app data.

After reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33234062/xpcerrordescription-string-0x3623a854-length-22-contents-connecti), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28795166/what-is-communications-error-os-xpc-error-in-xcode-6) & [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27276718/app-crash-when-trying-to-load-a-large-amount-off-data-into-my-app) question on Stackoverflow and viewing the stats I am sure it is XPC doing this due to App taking a lot of memory

I could probably introduce something like paging to retrieve only a limited number of contacts at one point and retrieve others as the tableview scrolls but the problem is I need all of them retrieved at one point or another (to send to my server), if the user decides to add those contacts to his team on my app so this is bound to happen then anyways. I am properly deallocating the data structures used to hold this vast amount of data but it never really gets around to that part anyways as it crashes while reading contacts from the address book. Also there are some loops going on to classify contacts, sort them alphabetically, filter out etc. so they also add to overhead. So basically the code is a mess but client party is relentless, overruling all the suggestions we made to refactor the code.

How do I get out of this mess?  Asking for suggestions would be off-topic due to being primarily opinion based maybe but I really need guidance from senior and experienced folks here on handling this thing.

TL;DR How do I handle enormous data sets when I need to send that data set completely and in filtered state to the server?